# Django populating a choice field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with four tables:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    acronym = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

class Alarm(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product) #NEW
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=35)
    image_file = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class File(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='item_product') #NEW
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class FileAlarm(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="alarm_created_by")
    alarm_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    alarm_type = models.ForeignKey(Alarm)
    alarm_comment = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
```

Unfortunatly I need to pass an `onChange` event to the form element of `FileAlarm.alarm_type` (which means the `queryset` in `__init__` wont work) so I need to populate the `choices=` variable of `ChoiceField`. I'm just wondering how to do that since I only want alarms that are `active` and linked to the same `product`s as the `File` which the `FileAlarm` is linked.

```
class FileAlarmForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,file,*args,**kwargs):
        super(FileAlarmForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['alarm'].queryset = Alarm.objects.filter(product__id=file.product_id)

    alarm_type = ChoiceField(required=True, widget=Select(attrs={'onChange':'updateAlarmImage'}))  # << ?!?
```

Comment: Here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442681/django-init-function-with-attrs-in-form the problem seems to be pretty much the same, or at least close to what you need. Try to see if it can work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the best way round it was:

```
class FileAlarmForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,file,*args,**kwargs):
        super(FileAlarmForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        p = Product.objects.get(id=file.product_id)
        self.fields['alarm_type'].widget = Select(attrs={'onchange':'updateAlarmImage'})
        self.fields['alarm_type'].queryset = Alarm.objects.filter(product=p)
```